# How to access a variable outside of a function (access from a loop)?

Tags: python, global-variables

I am working on accessing a variable outside of a function. Here is part of my code:

```
def main():
    trigger_gmm() = 0
    log = []
    def spatter_tracking_cb(ts, clusters):
        global trigger_gmm
        for cluster in clusters:
            log.append([ts, cluster['id'], int(cluster['x']), int(cluster['y']), int(cluster['width']),
                        int(cluster['height'])])
             if cluster['width'] >= 200:
                 trigger_gmm = 1
             else:
                 trigger_gmm = 0
             print(trigger_gmm)
while True:
    print(trigger_gmm)
    if trigger_gmm == 1:
        print("print something")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the output like this:

```
NameError: name 'trigger_gmm' is not defined
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three issues in that code:

1. `trigger_gmm() = 0` - You need to remove the parenthesis
2. You need to move the global variable definition up to the beginning of the main function
3. The `if __name__ == "__main__":` is not reached as it is after the while loop, you need to move it up.

EDIT:
I added a global declaration to the main module (above the main function) and inside the `spatter_tracking_cb` function. This is because you need to indicate that the variable `trigger_gmm` is a global variable whenever you use it.

This code seems to work for me:

```
global trigger_gmm


def main():
    global trigger_gmm
    trigger_gmm = 0
    log = []

    def spatter_tracking_cb(ts, clusters):
        global trigger_gmm
        for cluster in clusters:
            log.append([ts, cluster['id'], int(cluster['x']), int(cluster['y']), int(cluster['width']),
                        int(cluster['height'])])
            if cluster['width'] >= 200:
                trigger_gmm = 1
            else:
                trigger_gmm = 0
            print(trigger_gmm)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

while True:
    print(trigger_gmm)
    if trigger_gmm == 1:
        print("print something")
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I've tried the code but got this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'trigger_gmm' referenced before assignment

Comment: I edited the code above, can you test it?
I believe that we're running a different python env and it is behaving slightly differently, but the new code is according to the correct usage of global variables, so it should be ok.

Comment: The code worked! Thanks Yomach!

Comment: Awesome!if you could mark my answer as accepted that would be great 

Answer (score 0):

`trigger_gmm = 0`
Remove parenthesis.
You also don't need `global trigger_gmm` as this variable will be available within scope of main function.
https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#nested-functions-the-enclosing-scope

Answer (score 0):

I am no Python user, but from it looks like you are calling variables that are not in a "global" scope.

Every variable defined in a function or loop, is not accessible by another function unless stated so.

Try defining your variable outside of the function, or make it global
As stated before.

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)